# Good undergrad level graph theory book?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a good undergraduate level graph theory book. I tried to read Bondy and Murty's, but I struggled with the first part about isomorphisms (I think, because I haven't gone through a Topology course yet). So,  before reading those more difficult books, I want one that is easier to get acquainted with the subject but that is not a dumbed-down-graphs-for-dummies type of text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Google "graph theory for high school students".

Answer (score 6):

Many years ago, I started with Douglas West's [*Introduction to Graph Theory*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8120321421) and found it to clearly cover the basics.

Graduate-level study would definitely warrant a different style of a text, perhaps Diestel's [*Graph Theory*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3662536218) would be good for that.

Answer (score 1):

I can heartily recommend "Introduction to graph theory" written by Robin J. Wilson. This book explain in detail the basics of graph theory and more complicated aspects of it. Moreover I really like the language and the proofs are very intuitive.
You can read it [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/wilsongraph.pdf).

Comment: Maybe you mean "highly recommend" -- "hardly recommend" means it would be hard for you to recommend the book.

Comment: @littleO My guess was he meant "heartily recommend".

Comment: Yes, of course! It’s a typo. I’ve jest edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

Bolloba's Modern Graph Theory is graduate book, but it might be worth looking at since Graph Theory isn't built upon extensive theory anyway, not in same way say, you have to go through several courses on calculus before going onto rigorous analysis and higher subjects.

Answer (score 1):

[Introduction to Graph Theory](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/388049.Introduction_to_Graph_Theory), by Richard Trudeau (originally published under the title, Dots and Lines).